# Open .pack file (UNIX)

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, pack, cmsis

The [ARM CMSIS](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/cortex-m/cortex-microcontroller-software-interface-standard.php) library can be downloaded as a *.pack file. How can I open/'unpack'(?) it?

It seems there used to be a function, *unpack*, which has since been deprecated and delegated to *gzip*. However, *gunzip* does not seem to recognize the extension:

```
gzip: ARM.CMSIS.4.4.0.pack: unknown suffix -- ignored
```

*zcat* seems to read the file (it returns some formatted output that appear to be the contents, see below), but again fails with the following message (from *gzip*):

```
gzip: ARM.CMSIS.4.4.0.pack has more than one entry--rest ignored
```

(Some of zcat's output is shown below:)

```
    <example name="DSP_Lib Variance example" doc="Abstract.txt" folder="CMSIS/DSP_Lib/Examples/arm_variance_example/ARM">
      <description>DSP_Lib Variance example</description>
      <board name="uVision Simulator" vendor="Keil"/>
      <project>
        <environment name="uv" load="arm_variance_example.uvprojx"/>
      </project>
      <attributes>
        <component Cclass="CMSIS" Cgroup="CORE"/>
        <component Cclass="CMSIS" Cgroup="DSP"/>
        <component Cclass="Device" Cgroup="Startup"/>
        <category>Getting Started</category>
      </attributes>
    </example>
  </examples>

</package>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change the file extension from `.pack` to `.zip` and unzip it. As simple as that.

I did try that both on Windows with 7zip and linux - worked!